# APEX 5.0 Tabular form - Check if added row is empty

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have a tabular form that provides default values when a row is added.
When the user clicks to apply the changes with all of the defaults 0 rows are inserted into the table. If the user changes one value then the row is inserted.
It appears that validations are not checked because APEX thinks that the added row is empty.

How can I allow the added row to be processed when changes are not recognized, or how can I check for this scenario when the user clicks to apply changes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This could be a bug in the older version of apex. Maybe raise an SR with Oracle?
It is working fine in 19.1. The added row with defaults is getting stored in the database without having to make any changes before saving.